# Cannot Login into the localhost Wordpress

Tags: mysql, wordpress, localhost, lamp, credentials

I cannot login into my localhost WordPress. Initially,​ I thought my password is incorrect. So I changed my password in my database. After that also, It's not allowing me to login using the correct credential. Is there any suggestion?

Comment: How you changed password in db? You used md5 or just string on update?

Comment: I used md5 @Manjunath. Not a string.

Comment: Try adding new user, see if it works, if not then you might have to check the db

Comment: https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-add-an-admin-user-to-the-wordpress-database-via-mysql/ this wil.help you

Comment: I will try and let u know. thanks

Comment: It's not working @Manjunath.

Comment: Then Check wp-config.php which database it's referring to and make sure you are using the same

Comment: I checked and I am using the right database.

Answer (score 1):

You would try the following solution

solution 1:

- Go to the phpmyadmin
- Select the database
- select user table
- edit the respective user
- select the md5 for password field and enter the password
- hit the save button
- go to login screen and try with new password

Solution 2:

- Go to forgot password using login screen
- enter the email
- Set the new password using password reset link

  **Note** : for this solution you would need to setp the localhost for smtp to receive and send the emails

Comment: Could you please confirm are you enter the correct password? 
It should be resolve using solution2.

It may happen you may copy paste the password so that there would be a space. Please recheck

Comment: Sorry to say but I did exactly the same. Regarding the password reset link, even my email is not recognized.

Comment: Can anyone help, please? I have been stuck for 2 weeks.

Comment: Hey, Thank you. The problem was with my plugins. Thanks for responding.

Comment: I found [this article](https://www.wpexplorer.com/reset-wordpress-password-using-mysql/) helpful, it's roughly the same as in the answer above, but including the specific MySQL commands to type. In summary (slightly adapted) `use wordpress_db_name;` and `select * from wp_users;` to locate the correct user's ID (999 for example), then using the ID you just found `update wp_users set user_pass = MD5('put_new_password_here') where ID=999;`